# Как подключить FTP в Atom

Tags: ftp, localhost, atom

Скачал remote ftp, создал  конфиг файл, ввёл хост, юзера, пароль и указал путь. но соединение не проходит и пишет, что время истекло. в чем может быть причина?

```
{
"protocol": "ftp",
"host": "",
"port": 21,
"user": "",
"pass": "",
"promptForPass": false,
"remote": "",
"local": "",
"secure": false,
"secureOptions": null,
"connTimeout": 20000,
"pasvTimeout": 20000,
"keepalive": 20000,
"watch": [],
"watchTimeout": 1000
```

}

Comment: Столкнулся с той же проблемой. Если найду решение, то отпишу!

Answer (score 1):

Нашел причину и исправил. Что надо поменять: - в файле конфигурации подключения "host": надо прописать не доменное имя, а IP-ник, типа 192.ххх.ххх.ххх (у каждого он свой, мне выдавался при регистрации хостинга)